# Solving swift error: Cannot specialize a non-generic definition

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I recently converted an xcode project from xcode 7 to xcode 8 and in doing so, moved from swift 2.3 to 3. The app relies on pods and various frameworks. Currently, 5 of the errors are the same, the error is

> Cannot specialize a non-generic definition.
>   While parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket

I feel like once one of these errors are solved, I will be able to fix the rest. So here is the snippet of code where the error currently occurs

```
func getWordIndex(_ charIndex:Int) -> (start: Int, stop: Int) {

        let plainString =  self.fillerAttribString?.string

        var charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: Range<String.Index>( plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: charIndex) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: charIndex+1))!))


        var tCharIndex = charIndex
        var leftCharIndex = 0
        var rightCharIndex = (self.fillerAttribString?.length)! - 1
        for i in tCharIndex..<self.fillerAttribString!.length {
            charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: Range<String.Index>( plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: i) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: i+1))!))
            if (charAtIndex == " ")
            {
                rightCharIndex = i
                break
            }
        }

        tCharIndex = charIndex
        for i in (0..<tCharIndex).reversed(){


            charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: Range<String.Index>( plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: i) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: i+1))!))
            if (charAtIndex == " ")
            {
                leftCharIndex = i + 1
                break
            }
        }

        return (leftCharIndex, rightCharIndex);
    }
```

the error occurs currently on these lines

```
    var charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: Range<String.Index>( plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: charIndex) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: charIndex+1))!))

charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: Range<String.Index>( plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: i) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: i+1))!))

charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: Range<String.Index>( plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: i) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: i+1))!))
```

those are the 3 parts of the code in this function where this error is occurring.
Thank you in advance. I have looked around on here and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Other then getting errors with unwrapped optionals if the index was too big (or below 0), I retested this code a few times, seems to be working fine for me. Are you using generics in this class? anything related to this word function? I don't know, but I feel we need more information to be able to help. Since this code works fine on it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func getWordIndex(_ charIndex:Int) -> (start: Int, stop: Int) {

    let plainString =  self.fillerAttribString?.string

    var charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: charIndex) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: charIndex+1))!)


    var tCharIndex = charIndex
    var leftCharIndex = 0
    var rightCharIndex = (self.fillerAttribString?.length)! - 1
    for i in tCharIndex..<self.fillerAttribString!.length {
        charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: i) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: i+1))!)
        if (charAtIndex == " ")
        {
            rightCharIndex = i
            break
        }
    }

    tCharIndex = charIndex
    for i in (0..<tCharIndex).reversed(){


        charAtIndex = plainString?.substring(with: plainString!.characters.index(plainString!.startIndex, offsetBy: i) ..<  (plainString?.characters.index((plainString?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: i+1))!)
        if (charAtIndex == " ")
        {
            leftCharIndex = i + 1
            break
        }
    }

    return (leftCharIndex, rightCharIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `Range<String.Index>` initializer call since it seems what follows is already a string range.

Nevertheless, your style should work as well. For instance, all 3 forms all interchangeable:

```
let str = "foo"
let r0 = str.startIndex..<str.endIndex
let r1 = Range(str.startIndex..<str.endIndex)
let r2 = Range<String.Index>(str.startIndex..<str.endIndex)

r0 == r1 // true
r0 == r2 // true
```